# Four-velocity of radially infalling gas in Schwarzschild metric

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I am reading [this paper by Thorne, Flammang & Zytkow (1981)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1981MNRAS.194..475T/abstract), which discusses the dynamics of spherical accretion onto a black hole in the Schwarzschild metric ($c=G=1$ units):

$$ds^2=-(1-2M/r)dt^2+(1-2M/r)^{-1}dr^2+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$$

For a gas with inward velocity $v$ (as measured by an observer at rest in this metric), equations 2-3 of the paper give this expression for the four-velocity:
$$\mathbf{u}=y(1-2M/r)^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-vy\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$$
$$y\equiv\mathbf{u}\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=(1-2M/r)^{1/2}(1-v^2)^{-1/2}$$
$y$ is the so-called energy parameter, and it would be a constant if the trajectory was a geodesic.

I am having trouble understanding how to obtain this expression.  Here is what I tried so far:

- The velocity is $v=-\frac{dr}{dt}$ (minus sign because the gas is moving inward)
- The four-velocity components are usually written as $U^{\mu}=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}$, where $\tau$ is the proper time
- By the chain rule, $\frac{dr}{d\tau}=\frac{dr}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\tau}=-v\frac{dt}{d\tau}$
- The four-velocity as a vector is $\mathbf{u}=U^\mu\partial_\mu=U^\mu\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$

So that:
$$\mathbf{u}=\frac{dt}{d\tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\frac{dr}{d\tau}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \quad\\=\frac{dt}{d\tau}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-v\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)$$

Further, since $ds^2=-d\tau^2$, we have:
$$-1=-(1-2M/r)\left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right)^2+(1-2M/r)^{-1}\left(\frac{dr}{d\tau}\right)^2\\
=\left(\frac{dt}{d\tau}\right)^2\left(-(1-2M/r)+(1-2M/r)^{-1}v^2\right)
$$

I don't see how this can lead to the expression for the four-velocity from the paper, so I must be making a mistake somewhere.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

The velocity $v$ is not $dr/dt$. What the paper says is

> $v\quad$ inward velocity of gas as measured by an observer at fixed $r$ in his local proper reference frame

This means that you need to build an orthonormal frame from the $\{\partial/\partial^\mu\}$ vectors at a given spacetime point. Well, you can check that the vectors

$$\mathbf{e}_\hat{t} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2M/r}} \partial_t \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{e}_\hat{r} = \sqrt{1 - 2M/r} \partial_r$$

are orthonormal, satisfying $\mathbf{e}_\hat{t} \cdot \mathbf{e}_\hat{t} = -1$ and $\mathbf{e}_\hat{r} \cdot \mathbf{e}_\hat{r} = 1$. In terms of these, the four-velocity is

$$\mathbf{u} = \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-2M/r}} \mathbf{e}_\hat{t} - \frac{vy}{\sqrt{1-2M/r}} \mathbf{e}_\hat{r} = u^{\hat{\mu}} \mathbf{e}_\hat{\mu},$$

and we have that $v = -u^\hat{r}/u^\hat{t}$. Or, to put it another way, the four-velocity has the $\mathbf{u} = (\gamma, -\gamma v)$ structure we expect from special relativity.

---

What if we want to go the other way and write down an expression for the four-velocity? We start with our expressions for the orthonormal basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_\hat{\mu}$ and the four-velocity $\mathbf{u} = u^\hat{t} \mathbf{e}_\hat{t} + u^\hat{r} \mathbf{e}_\hat{r}$. From the special relativistic formula $\mathbf{u} = \gamma(v) \mathbf{e}_\hat{t} - \gamma(v) v \mathbf{e}_\hat{r}$ (which holds since we're in an orthonormal basis), we get that $u^\hat{t} = \gamma(v)$ and $u^\hat{r} = -\gamma(v) v$. Finally, going back to the $\partial_\mu$ basis, we find

$$\mathbf{u} = \frac{\gamma(v)}{\sqrt{1-2M/r}} \partial_t - \gamma(v) v \sqrt{1-2M/r} \partial_r.$$

This is the same as the given expression if we define $y = - \mathbf{u} \cdot \partial_t = - g_{tt} u^t$, which works out to $y = \gamma(v) \sqrt{1-2M/r}$.

Comment: Thanks, I did have a misconception about _which_ velocity _v_ is.  I see how this leads to the expression in the paper, but could you explain how to get the u components in this basis?

Comment: @SimonG. I just replaced the $\partial_\mu$ vectors in terms of the $\mathbf{e}_\hat{\mu}$, using that $\partial_t = \sqrt{1-2M/r} \mathbf{e}_t$ and so on.

Comment: But how would I get the expression for the four-velocity in the first place? Where do $y$ and $v$ come from if I'm starting from this orthonormal basis?

Comment: @SimonG. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that this connection between orthonormal bases and special relativity could be made.  It makes sense!

Answer (score 6):

[Javier's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/495390/81133) is correct, but here's another way of seeing it:  An observer's "local radial coordinate" $\tilde{r}$ and "local time coordinate" $\tilde{t}$ are defined such that the metric is (locally) $ds^2 = - d\tilde{t}^2 + d\tilde{r}^2$ (suppressing angular coordinates).  It is evident that under this definition, $d\tilde{t} = dt \sqrt{1 - 2M/r} $ and $d \tilde{r} = dr / \sqrt{1 - 2M/r}$.  Thus, 
$$
-v = \frac{d\tilde{r}}{d\tilde{t}} = \frac{1}{1 - 2M/r} \frac{dr}{dt}. 
$$
This implies that
$$
u^\mu = \frac{dt}{d\tau} \left( 1, \frac{dr}{dt} , 0, 0 \right) = \frac{dt}{d\tau} \left( 1, -\left(1 - \frac{2M}{r}\right) v, 0, 0 \right).
$$
Further requiring that $u^\mu u_\mu = -1$ then leads to 
$$
\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1 - 2M/r)(1 - v^2)}},
$$
which is equivalent to the expressions provided.

Comment: Although this is correct, one has to be careful, because the equations with the differentials don't necessarily define actual coordinate functions $\tilde{t}$ and $\tilde{r}$. The quotation marks around "local coordinates" are very important!

Comment: This answer is more intuitive to me.  The fact that local coordinates are equivalent to flat spacetime is only true exactly at point $p$ where the observer is, correct?

Comment: @Michael. Just a small correction, $dt/d\tau = (1-2M/r)^{-1/2}(1-v^2)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like this gives the *reverse* transformation that @Javier gets in his answer.   This answer gives $d\hat{t} = dt (1 - 2M/r)^{1/2}$, while Javier's answer below gives, $e_\hat{t} = e_t (1 - 2M/r)^{-1/2}$.  Am I misunderstanding the notation?

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix:  I believe that the difference is that my answer effectively deals with coordinate one-forms, while Javier's uses basis vectors.  So it's not surprising that they have "opposite" transformation rules.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix what Michael says is correct, we're dealing with dual objects so the transformations are inverses of each other. Both are correct.